# Outlook 2013 keeps on saying “1 is still unread” in the Inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, inbox

I have tried 3 workarounds to get rid of the Inbox saying “1 is still unread” and it will not leave.

1. I have right clicked to mark all as read.
2. I have typed read:no for the inbox mailbox AND All Mailboxes.
3. I went to Properties of my Inbox and Clear'd offline Items, closed  Outlook and re-opened but it still says 1 unread in my Inbox.

   Any other ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to hit the X in the top of the mailbox field! Craziness.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the original poster clearly stated they solved it in the following comment posted an hour after the question was posted “**I figured it out. I had to hit the X in the top of the mailbox field! Craziness.**”

Answer (score -1):

1. In the search field, type 'read:no'
2. Then change the selection to 'All Outlook Items'
3. Then click on 'Find more on the server'

There will be an actual unread e-mail which will appear. 
Simply read it and the problem is solved; it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

when searching for unread messages from the server, it showing some unread mails, those are already read. anyways we can fix the problem by marking as unread from here.
Step for getting unread messages from the server.

1. In the search field, type 'read:no'
2. Then change the selection to 'All Outlook Items'
3. Then click on 'Find more on the server